# Как вывести данные из разных таблиц asp.net mvc?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, mvc

я начинаю осваивать asp.net mvc у меня есть 4 таблицы:
Erors:

```
 public class Eror
{
    public int ErorId { get; set; }//первичный ключ

    public string TitleE { get; set; }

    public string SubtitleE { get; set; }

    public int TypeErorID { get; set; }
    // внешний ключ
    public TypeEror TypeEror { get; set; }

    public int ProgerID { get; set; }
    // внешний ключ
    public Proger Proger { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

Progers:

```
 public class Proger
{
    public int ProgerId { get; set; }

    public string TitleP { get; set; }

    public int TypeProgerID { get; set; }
    //внешний ключ 
    public TypeProger TypeProger { get; set; }
}
```

TypesErors:

```
 public class TypeEror
{
    public int TypeErorId { get; set; }
    public string NameTE { get; set; }
}
```

TypesProgers:

```
 public class TypeProger
{
    [Required]
    public int TypeProgerId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Название (заголовок)")]
    public string NameTP { get; set; }
}
```

я заметила что можно быстро создать в VS контроллер связанный с бд который также построит мне и создание и редактирование и удаление

вот такая строчка в контроллере главное страницы списка таблицы `Erors`:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var dataBaseContext = _context.Erors.Include(e => e.Proger).Include(e => e.TypeEror);
        return View(await dataBaseContext.ToListAsync());
    }
```

То есть я вижу, что он понимает что у меня есть 2 внешних ключа(причем хочу заметить что в таблице `Proger` есть ссылка на `TypeProger`

но я не понимаю как мне это все связать(сейчас вместо типов программистов и ошибок выводит id). я знаю sql и в WindowsForms просто строила вложенный запрос, но здесь в представлении только:

```
@model IEnumerable<KISQLite.Domain.Entities.Eror>
```

У меня в голове есть мысль что можно было бы дернуть как-то через `@ViewBag`, но в одном представлении может быть одна модель. может можно как то 4 таблицы объединить в одну модель?

Comment: Попробуйте создать класс для передачи информации в нем. Т.е. если надо передать две коллекции - в классе создать 2 property, которые перед передачей во вьюшку наполнить данными. И да - контроллер должен быть максимально простым - только получение сведений - никаких операций.  Посмотрите в сторону интерфейсов ;-)

Comment: извините, а вы не не могли бы объяснить что значит это строка? _context.Erors.Include(e => e.Proger).Include(e => e.TypeEror) для чего она нужна? если я уберу. то у меня перестанут выводиться поля-внешние ключи..но при этом я не могу с помощью этого достатьдругие данные

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.3.php С другой стороны: прежде чем учиться создавать сайты/контроллеры - почитайте про Entity Framework, LinQ, Dependency Injection и MVCв целом. ;-)

Comment: а все, до меня дошло. в вызове надо было прописать  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TypeEror.NameTE). но все равно спасибо за ссылки, я обязательно это еще поизучаю)

Comment: "в одном представлении может быть одна модель.", но вы можете использовать для использования в представлении, ViewModel,  а вот в самой ViewModel, вы можете засунуть все сущности, которые вам нужны. Вот в этом [комите](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky/commit/60a15427321b6ba933edd77b334610432f7ccc33) создается и далее используется ViewModel в ASP.NET Core MVC для .NET 5.